# Show Desktop/Workspaces/Active Windows by Hovering the mouse to any corner of the desktop

Tags: window-manager, workspaces, ubuntu-tweak

There is a way to show the "Desktop", "All Active Windows" and "Workspace Switcher" by just hovering ur mouse to the edges of the screen.

One way this can be done is using "Ubuntu Tweak".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The four corners of the desktop can be made put into use effectively by using to them "Show The Desktop" or as a "Workspace Switcher" or to "Show Active Windows". Something like the Gnome 3's top left corner.

I have done this on Unity and I don't know about the same working on Gnome 3.x.

```
11.10 onwards
```

Here's How, Install Ubuntu Tweak, execute the following Commands

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Once installed, please proceed to "Tweaks > Compiz Settings", under "Compiz Settings" configure the edges of ur screen to ur desired functionality.

> Show Desktop -> Minimizes all the window and brings focus to the
>   desktop (emulates Ctrl+Alt+D)
>
> Show Windows -> Shows all the active Windows (something like Alt+Tab,
>   but better)
>
> Show Workspaces -> Same function as the Workspace Switcher that u see
>   on the launcher.

Now u don't even need to click anything. Just touch the edges. :)

[image]

```
11.04
```

Install Ubuntu Tweak. Here's How,

Go To Software Center,

> Click Edit -> Software Sources -> Other Software Tab and click on Add

and add the following PPA to your Software Sources

> `ppa:tualatrix/ppa`

Close out and go back into Software Center.  Search and install "Ubuntu Tweak".

Now make the changes as shown in the screenshot.

[image]